# Laravel Aws Nginx Multiple Projects on one Elastic IP

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

I'm fairly new to AWS Laravel Deployment, I had been using Hostgator before and management of multiple domains is fairly easy there. however I'm quite limited with things I want to do so we decided to check out AWS.

What I have:

- ec2 instance
- elastic ip associated to the instance
- Installed Ubuntu 18.04
- Installed Nginx
- Laravel 8 Project

for now Im testing deployment of multiple projects. I created Multiple EC2 instances ( the free one). and I got it working. **the question** now is I want to leverage costing. **Is it possible to have only one instance running for multiple projects that doesnt have a domain yet.

like for ex:

- **staging project 1** is accessible @
  18.186.128.145:5000
- **staging project 2** is accessible @
  18.186.128.145:9000

I had been doing this on my local environment. I just dont know if its quite possible with AWS Nginx deployment

Here's my working Nginx Config File. ( Random IP in the example btw )

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 18.186.128.145;
    root /var/www/laravel/project-staging-1/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I have searched everywhere but all I could see are examples with a hosted domain name, or ones with sub folders or sub domains. If there is an existing answer please point it out to me I'll appreciate it.

I don't know yet if what im onto is actually possible. If you can, please give me advice on better move to do if this is not possible. Thank you so much

Comment: Create 2 config files one listening on port `5000` and another listening on port `9000`. I.e: instead of `listen 80;` use `listen 5000;` and so forth.

Comment: I edited the listen port and the project is no longer accessible either via port i written or just by the ip address alone

Comment: You can mark it as resolved by [posting/writing an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) explaining how you solved your issue. In addition, you may [accept your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) if no other answer fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it possible.

I already whitelisted the ports nginx is listening to in "ufw" **however**
it turns out, I also have "security groups" in my AWS Ec2 Instance where I also need to whitelist the ports i'm gonna be using.

- So Whitelist the ports in the inbound rules of the security group
- allow the ports in ufw
- edit the nginx config file to listen to the ports you want to use
- you may create multiple server blocks if you're planning to open up multiple ports.